# Reading number from a file and checking against a random generation

Tags: java, math, random, variable-assignment

**OBJECTIVE:**

Generate a random integer (from 1-99) and use the numbers.dat file (from the last lab) to determine if the generated random number is in the file. Do not count the number of times you find your random number, just output that it’s in the file or not in the file.

Possible pseudo-code:

1. Generate a random # from 1-99
2. Declare and initialize a Boolean variable to false
3. Loop until end of file or match found: Read number.
4. Compare numbers. If match, set Boolean var true
5. If Boolean is true the number was found else not found.

Part 2. Put all the code in Part 1 inside a for-loop so part 1 runs 3 times.
b. Output – Similar to the output below:

```
The random number 35 is in the file.
The random number 10 is not in the file.
The random number 9 is in the file.
```

**My Code:**

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class RandomNumberMatch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner num = new Scanner (new File ("numbers.dat"));
        Random ran = new Random();
        while(num.hasNext()) {
            int number = num.nextInt();
            int x = ran.nextInt(100);;

            if(number == x) {
                System.out.println("The number " + x + " is in the file");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("The number " + x + " is not in the file");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
The number 80 is not in the file
The number 52 is not in the file
The number 50 is not in the file
The number 76 is not in the file
The number 21 is in the file
The number 18 is not in the file
The number 40 is not in the file
(Cut short for summary purpose)
```

**Contents of file:**

```
16 43 56 8 12 35 65 12 26 3 65 4 75 86 9 79 0 78 5 78 4 63 65 3 53 64 7 5 87 6 96 96 70 7 95 78 46 4 37 46 3 53 93 84 76 56 48 93 3 74 76 46 5 47 38 4 39 4 84 57 46 37 48 4 9 84 7 36 3 0 58 6 7 84 7 5 6 4 9 30 4 3 8 4 7 4 4 55 76 4 53 6 47 5 85 74 63 2 3 45 48 73 63 5 21 42 21 55 1
```

What exactly am I doing wrong besides not nesting the output in a for loop, the majority of these numbers ARE in the file. I am trying to match it with my created random number and if they are equal output it to the file and then proceed to indicate if the number is in the file or not. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, I am very stuck on this and I just can't seem to figure it out!

Comment: I strongly suggest the use of a debugger here. Put a breakpoint before your _while_ and just step through and see what happens as to what you think should happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this seems like a school assignment I won't give you the code for the answer, but think about these questions:

You need to determine whether a random number exists in the entire file. So if you compare it to a single number from the file, do you have enough information to make the definitive statement that "The number is not in the file"?

Is it necessary to continue to loop through the entire file if you've already found the number you're looking for?

Comment: First of all, please calm down. Second, could you clarify what mistake I made?

Comment: +1: I think this was an appropriate and correct way to answer the question.

Comment: @Chris43234 I have to apologize I DIDNT READ IT CORRECTLY! I am sorry from my deepest heart, that was my mistake and not correct in any ways!

Comment: @user1902288 That being said, now that you have understood correctly and you have removed your comment, do not use vulgar language or curses on this site. That is not acceptable.

Comment: @user1902288 Glad to hear you're calm :-) The reason I asked OP if it was necessary to continue to loop through the file was to get him thinking about the question (I.E. he's not doing something correctly). Just saw your reply, no worries!

Comment: @Chris43234 The Socratic Method was strong today.

Comment: @Zéychin go report anyone that uses the accronym RTFM! then ;) (Message received, stessful day, no more 4 letter words, sorry)

Comment: @Chris43234 I am with you - hence the upvote - I will further point it out to him.

Answer (score 1):

O.k. i know its a Lab - i had hundreds of them - unfortunately just as in real live they tend to not have very good requirements. Oftenly not because they dont know how to write proper requirements but to . Lets therefore start by analyzing your requirements(objective):

*Generate a random integer (from 1-99) and use the numbers.dat file (from the last lab) to determine if the generated random number is in the file.*

I think this is pretty clear on what to do and there are literaly a tousand ways to archive it (i mean no one says to use Java in that sentence but cmon youre probably in a Java Lab :)). So lets continue because there are more "customer" requirements (and we want to statisfy our customer because he otherwise wont give us any money for beer).

*Do not count the number of times you find your random number, just output that it’s in the file or not in the file.*

O.k. we have a first issue right here (**Issue 1**). We do understand that we are not expected to count -but do we automaticially know now if we have to only output it once on first occurence or is it possible that a number can occure multiple times in the file and our customers expects the output on every occurence?

In real live hardening such details is the job of requirement engineers. 
BUT wait, there is even more! Our customer knows the word pseudo code! He already has a more detailed idear on how the solution should work inside - but we have to be REALY CAREFUL about this pseudo code because we dont know if the customer knows what he is doing (unfortunately its often the case that its not only our job to produce a solution but to find out how it should look). Alright, lets continue:

**Possible (e.g. COULD be a solution()!!!** pseudo-code:

*Generate a random # from 1-99 Declare and initialize a Boolean variable to false*

```
// your code
Random ran = new Random();
int x = ran.nextInt(100);
boolean hasNumber = false;
```

Case clear, lets continue:

*Loop until end of file **or** match found:*

Oh - we have a choice that has direct influence on our open Issue 1! (bad requirement!) Lets call this **Issue 2** and continue on "what a match is".

*Read number. Compare numbers. If match, set Boolean var true If Boolean is true the number was found else not found.*

If i have to know the number was found to set a Boolean to true to indicate the number was found i hardly question the need of a Boolean" but this is mostly because we dont want to end the programm on the first match but just stop looping over the file (and be able to decide if we found something or not afterwards).

Now rather than copy&paste the code refer to the answer from user @sto and note that at the point where you set your boolean to true you can add a return; statement to leave the loop even thus there would be more numbers (you found it) **OR** you can continue Looping because the requirement with issue 2 is not clear.

**The most important part**
Well one important part is that you want to be pointed to the right direction rather than get a complete solution you may not understand. Thats the way software developers think!

As you can see in the comments below this answer it is all about the requirements ... is it the fast way because it is a school assignment? Is it the long way because it could be too? Do the comments imply a clear and good requirement if the first two developers who cared about them are already making assumptations and argue on what the customer might want? **NO!**.

The very most important point of my entire answer is to point out how extremly important it is to have requirements that dont leave space for assumptations (they will still leave you a billion of ways on how exactly you code the according solution on a tech. level). So once you have a requirement that wouldnt make @me and user @Zéychin argue about the meaning - you know you have a good requirement and its worth to start to think about the solution.

I hope i could gave you something more valuable than just the solution for your Lab 2 (i assume you got it already fixed right?).

Comment: Thank you, @user1902288. I completely overlooked the boolean value and am trying to solve that issue all though my issue remains. I am very grateful for your assistance as you seem to be highly-skilled in what you do!

Comment: The requirements do say to loop *until a match is found* or until the end of the file, which would indicate to me that only a single output is expected for a match in the file, regardless of the number of matches in the file.

Comment: @Zéychin I see that point but you also have to see that i as a 15yrs+ developer interpreted it "wrong"! So what we have here is not a clear requirement because the "or" could also be interpreted as "we are free to abort on the first match OR continue after the first match" (semantics only)

Comment: It really depends on whether we short circuit the conditional statement, which is certainly up to choice. `if(x || y)` versus `if(x | y)`. Though, I have noticed that these assignments, if they do not clarify further, they mean the short-circuiting version.

Comment: @Zéychin Youre absolutly correct and i am totally with you - i will add one last sentence to my answer in the hope next generation developers see where the issues oftenly are made (its the requirements not the code in my experience)

Comment: @user1902288 and do not mistake my saying that this is the way it is usually done makes it okay. The requirements were made lazily. That being said, I think it would be best for OP to clarify with the assigner of the exercise rather than hash it out any further on here.

Comment: @Zéychin See my update in my answer - were all here to help and were all in one boat i guess. The only one that jumped out of the boat for a quick swin was me when i used a 4letter word in the comment section - hence my excuse in the answer above). Have a good weekend everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Ok what you are doing is only checking the random number against the one of the numbers in the text file, then you are checking a new random number against the next number in the text file.  If you move the int x - ran... out of the loop it should be fine, so:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class RandomNumberMatch
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
     Scanner num = new Scanner (new File ("numbers.dat"));
     Random ran = new Random();
     int x = ran.nextInt(100);
     int number;
     boolean hasNumber = false;
     while(num.hasNext())
     {
        number = num.nextInt();

        if(number == x)
        {
           System.out.println("The number " + x + " is in the file");
           hasNumber = true;
        }    
     }
     if(!hasNumber){
         System.out.println("The number " + x + " is not in the file");
     }
    }
   }
```

Comment: still leads to a similar problem but thank you for the assistance!

Comment: It does work, your problem is that you are printing it is not in the file after every pass I will edit the code further for you ;)

Comment: One important was now pointed out - but your main issue is of a very common kind in our business. A.) your requirements are shit (go tell your teacher a 15yrs+ experienced developer said that) B.) You dont follow your requirements.

Comment: p.s. I am not completing the rest of the requirements for you, just illustrating why it wasn't finding the variable

Comment: Thank you, I would prefer not being handed the code, just being pointed in the right direction. My mind is just all scrambled about this program.